# The optimal way to enter multiple addresses for the same record within a form?

Tags: database, forms, user-interface, ms-access

So I've been developing a sort of data entry platform within accessing using forms and subforms.

I have a form titled PHYSICIAN. Each physician will have basic data like first/last name, DOB, title, contract dates, etc. The aspect I'm wanting to cover is addresses as they may have multiple, since they may work/practice at 2 or 3 or even 10 different locations.

Instead of having our data entry team key in a full record each time they need to add an address, I'd like a way for the form to retain ALL information not related to the address.

So if Ken Bone works at 7 places, I want to allow them to key all of those addresses a bit more efficiently than creating a new record.

There's one main issue I'm running into --- A subform or autopopulate option doesn't necessarily increment the autonumber ID (primary key) for the record. All of the information is being stored in 1 master table.

Is there a way around this or a more logical approach that you folks might suggest?

Comment: The sub form will automatic update the auotnumber id, but that autonumber ID is not really much important, the important part is having the subform enter the PK value of the main doctor table. So every table will have a autonumber ID, but the "doctor address" table will also have a column called "doctor_ID" that will hold the PK value from the parent doctor record - the sub form will automatic enter these values for you with the link master/child settings.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you have a couple of tables perhaps even three.

**tblDoctorInfo**
 - Dr_ID
 - Name
 - DOB
 - Title

**tblAddresses**
 - AddressID
 - Address1
 - Address2
 - City
 - State
 - Zip
 - Country

**tblDr_Sites**
 - DrSites_ID
 - Dr_ID
 - AddressID

The tables might have data like this.

**tblDoctorInfo**

1, Bob Smith, 12/3/1989, Owner

2, Carl Jones, 1/2/1977, CEO

3, Carla Smith, 5/3/1980, ER Surgeon

**tblAddresses**

1, 123 Elm St, Fridley, MN 55038

2, 234 7th St, Brookdale, MN 55412

3, 345 Parl Ave, Clinton, MN 55132

**tblDr_Sites**

Then you could associate the tables with the third table.  (Note each of the three tables have an ID field that increments).

1,1,1 This record means Dr. Bob works in Fridley

2,1,2 This record means Dr. Bob works in Brookdale

3,3,1 This record means Dr. Carla works in Fridley

4,2,3 This record means Dr. Carl works in Clinton

5,2,2 This record means Dr. Carl works in Brookdale

6,2,1 This record means Dr. Carl works in Fridley

Comment: My only issue is this -- How do we make those associations? The data entry team here is getting an Excel spreadsheet with all of the info as a row of data. I'm not sure how that would work as far as the forms go. I'd much rather use a navigation form before I would a single form with a ton of subforms embedded within it.

Comment: You simple base the main form on the info for that doctor. And then drop in a sub form based on the addreses table. This will allow data entry of multiple address for the one record. So sub forms are how you add and enter related table data in a form - and Access will take care of entering the value in the column used to related back to the main doctor table/form.

Comment: So if the main form is info for that doctor, that table will have an ID, say recordID -- If I enter multiple addresses into that subform, will the ID key increment for each address we enter? We'll have 3-5 employees accessing the same DB at once, so the incrementing of recordID is very important

Comment: Yes, Steven. The main form is info for that Dr.

Comment: Yes, Steven. The main form is info for that Dr.  It can have the ID field called recordID (or something more descriptive like Dr_ID.)
Then the subform is a reference of Addresses.  It can have an ID field named AddressID.  
The way to link these is with the with the properties of the subform.  Look at the data tab and Link Master Fields/ Link Child Fields.  If you select the three dots [...] at the right of the property, a dialog will popup that helps you associate the subform and the parent form.

Comment: Look at the Googler for some additional resources: 
"How to Create Form and Subform in Microsoft Access - YouTube"
or a good article is "Add a subform" Microsoft Office support